# Subquery in Case Expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following data.

Output:

```
id  cid price   sold
--------------------
 1  1   10      20     
 2  1   30      40      
 3  2   50      60
```

What I need is this:

```
 id cid Amount
--------------
  1 1   20     
  2 1   10      
  3 2   30
```

If `id = cid` then sold as amount else

If `id != cid` then for cid's matching id's price as amount ( Please refer above output, if it is confusing! )

I have the following SQL query:

```
 declare @tg table(id int, cid int, price int, sold int)

 insert into @tg values(1, 1, 10, 20); 
 insert into @tg values(2, 1, 30, 40);
 insert into @tg values(3, 2, 50, 60);

SELECT 
    id, cid, 
    CASE WHEN id  = cid 
           THEN sold 
         WHEN B.id IN (SELECT 
                           CASE WHEN id != cid 
                                THEN cid 
                           END AS cid1 
                       FROM @tg A 
                       WHERE A.cid = B.id) 
           THEN price  
    END as amount 
FROM 
    @tg AS B
 --OR
select
id,cid,
CASE WHEN id  = cid THEN sold else price END as amount from @tg
 as B
```

it's not working when `id != cid`.

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement...

Comment: @jarlh Thanks :) Now is know the difference between CASE Expressions And Statements. 
difference is that the statement is finished with an END CASE statement rather than just END. The PL/SQL statements are essentially an alternative to lists of IF .. THEN .. ELSIF statements.

(https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/case-expressions-and-statements-9i)

Comment: And a case expression has a return value, while the case statement is just conditional execution of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,cid,case when id=cid then sold else (select price from @tg t1 where t1.id = t2.cid) end as amount
from @tg t2
```

I think thats what you are looking for, IF id=cid take sold, else > take the corresponding price from the sold table where cid = id

Comment: No problem, anytime.

Comment: So i feel now i know what is Co - related Subquery. 
And what is happening here is outer query is executed every time for the every record ( id  ) in the inner query ( cid ).

Answer (score 1):

Modify `SELECT` like this

```
select  id,cid, CASE WHEN id  = cid THEN sold 
  WHEN id  <>  cid 
      THEN price  
      END as amount from @tg
 as B
```

this will return sold when `id  = cid` other wise `Prize`

Comment: That's not even correct why is he getting the upvote? He wanted the price of the corresponding ID=CID not of the ID<>CID

Comment: select  id,cid, CASE WHEN id  = cid THEN sold 
  else price  
      END as amount from @tg
 as B
This is same as your answer, And here you no need to write " WHEN id  <>  cid " because false condition will always end in ELSE part. But this is not the correct answer because it not check for id = cid conditions for (else part of the data). Anyway good try :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  id, 
  cid, 
  case when cid = id then sold 
    else (select price from @tg where id=c.cid )
  end as amount  
from @tg c
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. It is currently viewed as a low quality post. Thanks!

Comment: i've used  correlated subquery . here  when it goes to case it checks  cid=id of  @tg as  c table it correct it prints sold else goies to else part then later it fetches the  outer query cid  no and gives it to inner table as value to id then it fetches the price

Answer (score 0):

I think this is clearer just as a join:

```
select tg.*, tgc.price as sold
from @tg tg left join
     @tg tgc
     on tg.cid = tgc.id;
```

You are just looking up the value in the same table.  You don't actually need to short-circuit the `join`.

Or, if you prefer a subquery:

```
select tg.*,
       (select tgc.amount from @tg tgc where tgc.id = tg.cid)
 from @tg tg;
```

In both these cases, it is important to use table aliases.  Otherwise, you cannot distinguish between the temporary tables.

Comment: we have NO amount column, it alias column name derived from price & sold column